# Does running "./something.sh" considered as idle?

Tags: ssh, timeout, process

The file `./something.sh` contains multi thousands of complex jobs. this should take long time. I just simply run `./something.sh` without any other command, and I must wait until it finished.

I connecting to this Ubuntu server through SSH. Now `./something.sh` has run nearly 2 hours and still not finished its job.

I'm worried if this job considered as idle and server close my connection by giving `Write failed: Broken pipe` message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, you should use some sort of job control (`fg`, `bg`, `nohup`) or try using the `screen` utility to allow you to detach from a session while a script or command runs.

For the existing command, can you open another ssh session and run `ps aux | grep` to check the running status of the process?

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not. Also, I stronly recommend using screen or tmux for this kind of jobs. With this, you start screen, start your job inside it, detach it, disconnect and after a while you can reconnect, reattach the screen session and see if your process is finished.

Also, some kind of logging or status reporting in your script would help you a lot with long-running jobs.